# Explicit call to base copy constructor => RTTI info lost. Bug?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, rtti, dynamic-cast

**First of all:**

I ask this question just out of curiosity, to understand what's *really* happening. I don't use in production code like this so I *don't* want to see answers suggesting another solution.

Having this code:

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void copy(){}
};

class Derived: public Base{
public:
    void copy(){
        Base a1;
        this->Base::Base(a1);//explicit call to base copy constructor
    }
};
```

I know that for some cases it is not good to call explicitly the copy constructor.(when classes have members allocated dynamically, because the reference to that memory area will be lost and it will not be freed anymore).

For the bellow example I don't see any direct problem for calling the base copy constructor. At the first sight I would think that the base sub-object must be reinitialized when `copy()` method is called.

```
int main(){
    Base** _a = new Base*;
    _a[0] = new Derived(10);
    Derived* b = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(_a[0]);
    assert(b);//<===true
    _a[0]->copy();
    //t is still available and can be accessed through b
    std::cout<<b->t;//correct: 10
    b = (Derived*)_a[0];
    std::cout<<b->t;//correct: 10
    b = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(_a[0]);
    assert(b);//<===false       
}
```

However the second assert fails. Can someone explain this behaviour? Why is this happening ? Is typeid lost when calling base copy constructor?

I compiled the code with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile...

Comment: @KerrekSB I did not exect to compile either but I was trying some stuff and I realised that it compiles and I wanted to know what happens.

Comment: It compiles because it's the same with pointer to member functions. Having A::*t you can call (this->*t)()

Comment: What on earth are you doing....?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit just some fun experiments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructor before class members initialization set the vptr pointer to the virtual function table of that class. Manually calling constructor of parent class you make derived class vptr point to vtable of the parent class.

Comment: It's interesting, I checked and the __vfptr is actually changed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you call `Base::Base(const Base&)`, you are creating a new object of type `Base` in the memory allocated for your object of type `Derived`. After that, all virtual functions, for instance, will point to their `Base::` implementations.

If you want to reinitialize your object, you must call the constructor of the derived type `Derived::Derived(const Derived&)`, you can't just reinitialize part of it.

Aside:
You can make the reinitializetion correct by first destructing the object:

```
this->~Derived();    //cleanly destruct the object
this->Derived::Derived(...);    //rebuilt the object in place
```